# Конструктор наследника с вызовом конструктора базового класса. Что писать в .h и .cpp?

Tags: c++, наследование, конструктор

Вот это у меня написано в .h-файле

```
Category() : Menu() {};
Category(std::string name) : Menu(name) {};
Category(std::string name, int posNumb) : Menu(name, posNumb) {};
```

А вот это в .cpp (то что в теле конструкторов это инициализация полей `Category`)

```
Category::Category() : Menu()
{
    EItems = nullptr;
    isize = 0;
}
Category::Category(std::string name) : Menu(name)
{
    EItems = nullptr;
    isize = 0;
}
Category::Category(std::string name, int posNumb) : Menu(name, posNumb)
{
    EItems = nullptr;
    isize = 0;
}
```

Если в определении ничего про базовый конструктор не писать, то компилятор в принципе и не ругается. Как надо-то? В инете полно инфы как их наследовать, но не могу найти про вынесение всего этого за пределы класса. Тоже самое с конструктором копирования. И как быть с перегруженными операторами(например присваивания), их виртуальными просто сделать?

Comment: *В инете полно инфы как их наследовать* -- а в "инете" нет разве учебников по азам программирования?

Comment: Да у меня и дома есть учебник Лафоре по ООП, который я изучил еще полгода назад. Пересмотрел кучу видео-курсов, которые как пишут в комментариях полностью повторяют учебники. Смотрел университетские лекции в том числе про препроцессор, объектные файлы, линковку. И такие нюансы там не объясняют. И я даже не знаю в каком разделе учебника это искать. Наследование и вынос конструкторов за пределы класса это две совершенно разные темы. Возможно я просто чего-то не понял. Вы бы еще сказали "а разве у вас в городе нет ВУЗов?" Всего пять лет обучения и ошибка в программе исправлена))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если в определении ничего про базовый конструктор не писать, то компилятор в принципе и не ругается.

Странное и неверное заявление. Базовый конструктор тут вообще ни при чем. В заголовочный файл для класса `Category` вы поместили инициализацию базового класса и тела конструкторов в виде `{}`. В файл реализации вы снова поместили инициализацию базового класса и еще одни тела ваших конструкторов в виде `{ что-то }`. Этим нарушено Правило Одного Определения. У одной и той же функции не может быть два тела. Зачем вы два раза определяете тело для каждого конструктора?

Либо помещайте определения в заголовочный файл, либо в файл реализации. Вот и все. Все это должно присутствовать только в *одном* месте.

Ваши определения конструкторов в файле реализации выглядят нормально. Зачем вы тогда написали инициализацию базового класса и какие-то `{}` в заголовочном файле?

> И как быть с перегруженными операторами(например присваивания), их виртуальными просто сделать?

Здесь вообще непонятно о чем идет речь. При чем здесь виртуальность вообще?

Comment: `{}` мне VS подсказала поставить. Я ее имел ввиду, когда сказал не "ругается". Я еще не компилировал, переписываю программу полностью. Там 1500 строк кода) Я понял, в объявлении не надо указывать какой конструктор базового класса вызывать. "При чем здесь виртуальность вообще?". Согласен это уже другая тема. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1 - объявление и реализация в одном .h файле.

```
class A {
public:
    A():
      m_a{}
    {}
private:
    int m_a;
};

class B: public A{
public:
     B(): 
       A(),
       m_b{"hello"}
     {}
private:
    std::string m_b;
}
```

Р. Лафоре ООП в С++. Глава 9 - Наследование. Разделы "Конструкторы производного класса" (в 4-ом издании - страница 368); "Наследование в классе Distance" (в 4-ом издании - страница 373).

Вариант 2 - когда реализация конструкторов выносится в .cpp файл

```
//.h
#include "A.h"
class B: public A{
public:
   B();
private:
    std::string m_b;
}

// .cpp 
#include "B.h"
B::B():
    A(),
    m_b{"hello"}
{}
```

И да, инициализацию полей обычно пишут в списке инициализации

Comment: Не поверите, я, перед тем как вы это написали, перечитал эту главу в электронном виде, т. к., как оказалось, книга на другой квартире осталась. Какое там издание было не помню. Но не было там такого, по крайней мере в этих главах. И в той книге, что я скачал тоже нет. А то что там есть я и так знал. Меня интересовало как правильно написать прототип и реализацию. Т. е. когда именно нужно компилятору сообщить что определенный конструктор `B()` вызывает какой-то конкретный конструктор класса `A()` в момент объявления или определения. Но за пример кода спасибо, может кому-нибудь пригодится.